# Problems with inheritance with Symfony2, Doctrine2

Tags: inheritance, symfony, annotations, doctrine

I edited some mistakes and details...

Well, I have been trying to create a inheritance with Product as parent and Film and Book as childs. Checking online and the official documentation didn't solved my problem because examples are poor and incomplete. (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

I'm not sure if I did it right and now I just don't know how to generate, manipulate and persist inherited objects.

Parent class

```
<?php
namespace Paf\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({ "film" = "FilmE2" , "book" = "BookE2" })
*/

class ProductEjemplo2 
{

/**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
//More fields, Name, Description ...
}
```

Child Class

```
<?php 
//Paf\MyBundle\Entity\FilmE2
namespace Paf\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class FilmE2 extends ProductEjemplo2
{
/**
  * @var integer $id
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  */
 protected $id;
}
```

doctrine:schema:update --force generates 2 tables:
ProductE...(id primary key, disc dunno how works, rest of fields)
FilmE2(id primary key, rest of fields)

```
public function create2Action()  
{
$product1 = new ProductEjemplo2();
$product1->setName('New Film 1'); //and more fields
//here $product1 ID is null.(autogenerated but yet without value)
$em->persist($product1); //error, non-object....
$em->flush();

$film = new FilmE2();
$film->setName('New Film 1'); //and more fields
$film->setDirector('dir1');
$film->setId(1);
$em->persist($film); //error, non-object....
$em->flush();
//In both cases happens the same.
```

This doesn't work, it's quite obvious because says **error "non-object" cant be persisted**... but if I try with a new Filme2() happens the same... I realized that the ID of product is autogenerated when I use flush(). So isn't generated when I use persist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two primary keys in inherited class, simply because it lets you to persist base object class. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/tests/Gedmo/Tree/Fixture/Transport) it works fine. Except that its more complicated to use queries witch should filter specific instances but everything is possible